# Yahoo purecss horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

Menu does not work on local pc

As you can see in image [htmt on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqeD8.png), the menu is ruleless on my pc...

But when I run the code on codepen `https://codepen.io/djary/pen/EGOpYZ` it  works fine! (all css and js code included).

**Pure version:** 1.0.0
**Browser name and version:** Google Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Note:** Locally, it only works with Firefox but when use other browser like chrome when using codepen it's ok,on local with chrome ...

```css
.pure-col-1,
.pure-col-1-1,
.pure-col-1-2,
.pure-col-1-3,
.pure-col-2-3,
.pure-col-1-4,
.pure-col-3-4,
.pure-col-1-6,
.pure-col-5-6,
.pure-col-1-12,
.pure-col-2-12,
.pure-col-3-12,
.pure-col-4-12,
.pure-col-5-12,
.pure-col-6-12,
.pure-col-7-12,
.pure-col-8-12,
.pure-col-9-12,
.pure-col-10-12,
.pure-col-11-12,
.pure-col-12-12 {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-rendering: auto;
}

.pure-col-1-12 {
    width: 8.3333%;
    *width: 8.3023%;
}

.pure-col-1-6,
.pure-col-2-12 {
    width: 16.6667%;
    *width: 16.6357%;
}

.pure-col-1-4,
.pure-col-3-12 {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.9690%;
}

.pure-col-1-3,
.pure-col-4-12 {
    width: 33.3333%;
    *width: 33.3023%;
}

.pure-col-5-12 {
    width: 41.6667%;
    *width: 41.6357%;
}

.pure-col-1-2,
.pure-col-6-12 {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.9690%;
}

.pure-col-7-12 {
    width: 58.3333%;
    *width: 58.3023%;
}

.pure-col-2-3,
.pure-col-8-12 {
    width: 66.6667%;
    *width: 66.6357%;
}

.pure-col-3-4,
.pure-col-9-12 {
    width: 75%;
    *width: 74.9690%;
}

.pure-col-5-6,
.pure-col-10-12 {
    width: 83.3333%;
    *width: 83.3023%;
}

.pure-col-11-12 {
    width: 91.6667%;
    *width: 91.6357%;
}

.pure-col-1,
.pure-col-1-1,
.pure-col-12-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 35.5em) {
    .pure-col-sm-1,
    .pure-col-sm-1-1,
    .pure-col-sm-1-2,
    .pure-col-sm-1-3,
    .pure-col-sm-2-3,
    .pure-col-sm-1-4,
    .pure-col-sm-3-4,
    .pure-col-sm-1-6,
    .pure-col-sm-5-6,
    .pure-col-sm-1-12,
    .pure-col-sm-2-12,
    .pure-col-sm-3-12,
    .pure-col-sm-4-12,
    .pure-col-sm-5-12,
    .pure-col-sm-6-12,
    .pure-col-sm-7-12,
    .pure-col-sm-8-12,
    .pure-col-sm-9-12,
    .pure-col-sm-10-12,
    .pure-col-sm-11-12,
    .pure-col-sm-12-12 {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-spacing: normal;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-rendering: auto;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-1-12 {
        width: 8.3333%;
        *width: 8.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-1-6,
    .pure-col-sm-2-12 {
        width: 16.6667%;
        *width: 16.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-1-4,
    .pure-col-sm-3-12 {
        width: 25%;
        *width: 24.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-1-3,
    .pure-col-sm-4-12 {
        width: 33.3333%;
        *width: 33.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-5-12 {
        width: 41.6667%;
        *width: 41.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-1-2,
    .pure-col-sm-6-12 {
        width: 50%;
        *width: 49.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-7-12 {
        width: 58.3333%;
        *width: 58.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-2-3,
    .pure-col-sm-8-12 {
        width: 66.6667%;
        *width: 66.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-3-4,
    .pure-col-sm-9-12 {
        width: 75%;
        *width: 74.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-5-6,
    .pure-col-sm-10-12 {
        width: 83.3333%;
        *width: 83.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-11-12 {
        width: 91.6667%;
        *width: 91.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-sm-1,
    .pure-col-sm-1-1,
    .pure-col-sm-12-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    .pure-col-md-1,
    .pure-col-md-1-1,
    .pure-col-md-1-2,
    .pure-col-md-1-3,
    .pure-col-md-2-3,
    .pure-col-md-1-4,
    .pure-col-md-3-4,
    .pure-col-md-1-6,
    .pure-col-md-5-6,
    .pure-col-md-1-12,
    .pure-col-md-2-12,
    .pure-col-md-3-12,
    .pure-col-md-4-12,
    .pure-col-md-5-12,
    .pure-col-md-6-12,
    .pure-col-md-7-12,
    .pure-col-md-8-12,
    .pure-col-md-9-12,
    .pure-col-md-10-12,
    .pure-col-md-11-12,
    .pure-col-md-12-12 {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-spacing: normal;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-rendering: auto;
    }

    .pure-col-md-1-12 {
        width: 8.3333%;
        *width: 8.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-1-6,
    .pure-col-md-2-12 {
        width: 16.6667%;
        *width: 16.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-1-4,
    .pure-col-md-3-12 {
        width: 25%;
        *width: 24.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-1-3,
    .pure-col-md-4-12 {
        width: 33.3333%;
        *width: 33.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-5-12 {
        width: 41.6667%;
        *width: 41.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-1-2,
    .pure-col-md-6-12 {
        width: 50%;
        *width: 49.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-7-12 {
        width: 58.3333%;
        *width: 58.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-2-3,
    .pure-col-md-8-12 {
        width: 66.6667%;
        *width: 66.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-3-4,
    .pure-col-md-9-12 {
        width: 75%;
        *width: 74.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-5-6,
    .pure-col-md-10-12 {
        width: 83.3333%;
        *width: 83.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-11-12 {
        width: 91.6667%;
        *width: 91.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-md-1,
    .pure-col-md-1-1,
    .pure-col-md-12-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    .pure-col-lg-1,
    .pure-col-lg-1-1,
    .pure-col-lg-1-2,
    .pure-col-lg-1-3,
    .pure-col-lg-2-3,
    .pure-col-lg-1-4,
    .pure-col-lg-3-4,
    .pure-col-lg-1-6,
    .pure-col-lg-5-6,
    .pure-col-lg-1-12,
    .pure-col-lg-2-12,
    .pure-col-lg-3-12,
    .pure-col-lg-4-12,
    .pure-col-lg-5-12,
    .pure-col-lg-6-12,
    .pure-col-lg-7-12,
    .pure-col-lg-8-12,
    .pure-col-lg-9-12,
    .pure-col-lg-10-12,
    .pure-col-lg-11-12,
    .pure-col-lg-12-12 {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-spacing: normal;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-rendering: auto;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-1-12 {
        width: 8.3333%;
        *width: 8.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-1-6,
    .pure-col-lg-2-12 {
        width: 16.6667%;
        *width: 16.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-1-4,
    .pure-col-lg-3-12 {
        width: 25%;
        *width: 24.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-1-3,
    .pure-col-lg-4-12 {
        width: 33.3333%;
        *width: 33.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-5-12 {
        width: 41.6667%;
        *width: 41.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-1-2,
    .pure-col-lg-6-12 {
        width: 50%;
        *width: 49.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-7-12 {
        width: 58.3333%;
        *width: 58.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-2-3,
    .pure-col-lg-8-12 {
        width: 66.6667%;
        *width: 66.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-3-4,
    .pure-col-lg-9-12 {
        width: 75%;
        *width: 74.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-5-6,
    .pure-col-lg-10-12 {
        width: 83.3333%;
        *width: 83.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-11-12 {
        width: 91.6667%;
        *width: 91.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-lg-1,
    .pure-col-lg-1-1,
    .pure-col-lg-12-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 80em) {
    .pure-col-xl-1,
    .pure-col-xl-1-1,
    .pure-col-xl-1-2,
    .pure-col-xl-1-3,
    .pure-col-xl-2-3,
    .pure-col-xl-1-4,
    .pure-col-xl-3-4,
    .pure-col-xl-1-6,
    .pure-col-xl-5-6,
    .pure-col-xl-1-12,
    .pure-col-xl-2-12,
    .pure-col-xl-3-12,
    .pure-col-xl-4-12,
    .pure-col-xl-5-12,
    .pure-col-xl-6-12,
    .pure-col-xl-7-12,
    .pure-col-xl-8-12,
    .pure-col-xl-9-12,
    .pure-col-xl-10-12,
    .pure-col-xl-11-12,
    .pure-col-xl-12-12 {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-spacing: normal;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-rendering: auto;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-1-12 {
        width: 8.3333%;
        *width: 8.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-1-6,
    .pure-col-xl-2-12 {
        width: 16.6667%;
        *width: 16.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-1-4,
    .pure-col-xl-3-12 {
        width: 25%;
        *width: 24.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-1-3,
    .pure-col-xl-4-12 {
        width: 33.3333%;
        *width: 33.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-5-12 {
        width: 41.6667%;
        *width: 41.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-1-2,
    .pure-col-xl-6-12 {
        width: 50%;
        *width: 49.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-7-12 {
        width: 58.3333%;
        *width: 58.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-2-3,
    .pure-col-xl-8-12 {
        width: 66.6667%;
        *width: 66.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-3-4,
    .pure-col-xl-9-12 {
        width: 75%;
        *width: 74.9690%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-5-6,
    .pure-col-xl-10-12 {
        width: 83.3333%;
        *width: 83.3023%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-11-12 {
        width: 91.6667%;
        *width: 91.6357%;
    }

    .pure-col-xl-1,
    .pure-col-xl-1-1,
    .pure-col-xl-12-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>InfoIna</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pure.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid-old-ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
    <!--<![endif]-->
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="pure-g">
        <!-- نوار نازک بالا -->
        <div class="pure-col-1">
            <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
                <a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading pure-menu-link">BRAND</a>
                <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">News</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Sports</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Finance</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--پایان نوار نازک بالا -->

    <!-- منوی بالا (منوی اصی) -->
    <div></div>
    <!-- پایان منوی بالا (منوی اصی) -->

    <!-- شروع نقشه -->
    <div></div>
    <!-- پایان نقشه -->
    </div>
    <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you accessing the page directly usin the html file (file:////some/path/file.html) or via a webserver on your machine (http://localhost/file.html) ?

Comment: @JoSSte directly page file:///C:/Users/Arman%20Es/Desktop/infoina%20theme/theme%20v.1/index.html

Comment: some browsers will not treat js as secure when you open the html directly. the solution is to use a local ngnix/apache/some-othe-webserver to view the file. this is to avoid XSS

Comment: @JoSSte only use css files , Even I deleted all the files except pure.css and grid.css